# Can we use Decorator design pattern inside MVC design pattern?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I am new to spring mvc framework. I have implemented spring web application that is designed in MVC design pattern. Now, I want to implement my own designed metrics for my spring api's. So, I just want to know that whether I should use decorator design pattern for metrics implementation or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "In general" you could easily have a MVC framework that supports the decorator pattern.

For spring in particular, Yes, you 'can' do it (I don't know personally how to)
But here is a SO question about it explaining how to fix someone else's implementation of it. (So it 'can' be done)

[sitemesh and spring MVC decorator pattern problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859014/sitemesh-and-spring-mvc-decorator-pattern-problems)